# Having troubles with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol

So I am getting a bizarre error when using UIPickerView. Before jumping into the code, a basic explanation of the app is in order:

This app uses a UISegmentedControl to select from a few different possibilities. Based on the selection from the segmented control, the UIPickerView is populated with different arrays. The picker view is guaranteed to have two (no more, no less) components. The arrays are of different sizes, this is where I run into the snag. I have some tests set up in the code to keep the values within the range of the arrays, but something is not working right.

Now onto the code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSMutableArray *array;
    int x = self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (x == 0) {
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.length];
    }
    else if (x == 1) {
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.time];
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.speed];
    }

    //component == 0 has no problems whatsoever
    if (component == 0) {
        if (row < [array count]){
            self.label1.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
            self.component0 = row;
        }
        else {
            self.label1.text = [array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1];
            self.component0 = (NSInteger)([array count] - 1);
        }
    }
    //component == 1 has problems, it always thinks that the row number is less than the array count
    else if (component == 1) {
        if (row < [array count]){
            self.label2.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
            self.secondComponent = row;
        }
        else {
            self.label2.text = [array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1];
            self.secondComponent = (NSInteger)([array count] - 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Components out of range");
    }

    //If I comment out this part, the program works as expected
    if (x == 0) {
        [self convertLength];
    }
    else if (x == 1) {
        [self convertTime];
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        [self convertSpeed];
    }
}
```

The error comes when trying to read a value from an array, this is the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'

I get this error when I go the the second segment (time) and scroll all the way to the bottom on the second component, and then go to the first index.
If I try to do the same thing with the first component, it works exactly the way it is supposed to, hence I am very confused, as I use basically the exact same code to control the two components.

This is how I load/reload the picker view:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int x = 0;

    if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        x = [self.length count];
    }
    else if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        x = [self.time count];
    }
    else if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        x = [self.speed count];
    }

    return x;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *string;
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.length];
    }
    else if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.time];
    }
    else if (self.segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.speed];
    }
    if (row >= [array count]) {
        string = [array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1];
        NSLog(@"Out of Range");
    }
    else {
        string = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return string;
}

- (IBAction)segmentDidChange:(id)sender {
    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [self pickerView:self.pickerView didSelectRow:self.component0 inComponent:0];
    [self pickerView:self.pickerView didSelectRow:self.secondComponent inComponent:1];
}
```

Other useful information:
length array count: 8
time array count: 9
speed array count: 8

When I log the variables, they behave the way they are expected to, they change their value to be within the range of the "controller array" before I try to access any data within said array, but for whatever reason the second component wants to access an index not contained within the array.

Comment: How are you creating the contents of the pickerView? Could you be setting the contents to the length of the largest array?

Comment: I updated the question to include the relevant code.